# glGetAttribLocation/glGetUniformLocation returns 0, causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS on glDrawArrays call (iOS)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, exc-bad-access

I am creating a simple OpenGL ES 2.0 application for iOS, and whenever I call glDrawArrays. I found that this was occurring when I had previously called glEnableVertexAttribArray for my two attributes (position and color), and then found that glGetAttribLocation was returning 1 for position, and 0 for color, and then also found that glGetUniformLocation was returning 0 for my MVP matrix. I am not sure if 0 is a valid value, or why glEnableVertexAttribArray appears to be causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS when glDrawArrays is called.

Here is my code:

compileShaders function:

```
-(void)compileShaders {
GLuint vertShader = [self compileShader:@"Shader" ofType:GL_VERTEX_SHADER];
GLuint fragShader = [self compileShader:@"Shader" ofType:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER];

GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(program, vertShader);
glAttachShader(program, fragShader);
glLinkProgram(program);

GLint success;
glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
if (success == GL_FALSE) {
    GLchar messages[256];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(program, sizeof(messages), 0, &messages[0]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:messages]);
    exit(1);
}

glUseProgram(program);

_positionSlot = glGetAttribLocation(program, "position");
_colorSlot = glGetAttribLocation(program, "color"); //Returns 0
_mvpSlot = glGetUniformLocation(program, "MVP"); //Returns 0

if (!_positionSlot || !_colorSlot || !_mvpSlot) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve the locations of the shader variables:\n Position:%i\n Color:%i\n MVP:%i", _positionSlot, _colorSlot, _mvpSlot); //Prints out the values of 1, 0, 0
}

glEnableVertexAttribArray(_positionSlot);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_colorSlot);
```

My render function:

```
-(void)render:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink {
glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

GLfloat mvp[16] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

glUniformMatrix4fv(_mvpSlot, 1, 0, mvp);

glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(_colorSlot, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

[_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

And my vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 color;

uniform mat4 MVP;

varying vec4 v_color;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = MVP * position;
    v_color = color;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

0 is a valid value, -1 is the "error" or "not found" value. The space for uniform locations and attrib locations is separate, so it's fine to have both a location 0 uniform and a location 0 attribute.

You should post the vertices and colors arrays to check if they have the right sizes, this is likely to cause a crash.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and no solution, however I have tried to extensively debug, so I thought perhaps it might be helpful to share.

I traced the issue down to `glCreateProgram()` and `glCreateShader()` calls. They both return zero, which is the error return. However in both cases `glGetError()` returns `GL_NO_ERROR`. In fact no error pops up all the way through the compile and link chain following the create calls.

I have the same symptom that `glGetAttribLocation` and also uniforms always return zero (rather than -1 for error!). But I can even feed broken shader files and it will not lead to a compile error or any log info. The correct string was checked to be fed into to compile.

I am completely dumbfounded by the behavior, because clearly `glCreateProgram` errors but doesn't set an error. And it is not clear to me at all why it does error. What is especially confusion is that a whole chain of GL function calls don't return errors. I am getting my first error when I the program calls a gl function that operates on a uniform, such as `glUniformMatrix4fv()` or `glUniform1i()`. But clearly things are broken way before then, because all uniforms return as 0 even though they cannot all be zero.

Edit: *I found the solution in my case*. Opengles1 seems to be quite flexible when framebuffers are set up. But I needed to force framebuffer setup before starting with shaders to get rid of the issue. e.g. if one follows the old eaglview template, framebuffers are created in `layoutSubviews`, however that is too late for a typical initialization of shaders in say `initwithcoder`. The symptoms are the above otherwise.

Comment: @Matias: Actually no. 0 is the error return for both glCreateProgram() and glCreateShader(). See http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCreateShader.xml and http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCreateProgram.xml. Now that it is fixed for me, I get non-zero returns for each.